# Use data in a tablespace to populate another postgres database instance without actually inserting

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a postgres database (version 8.4) with many tables. Some tables are huge in size, but the data is static (common for any instance). I have stored such tables in a separate tablespace. Is there a way to use this existing data. Or can I create another database instance (may be on a separate server) and create empty `bigTable` and point to the existing tablespace to populate the data in the existing `bigTable`?

Can I use the existing data in a tablespace to be populated in another postgres database instance without actually inserting the data, as reinserting the whole data takes so much time.

I tried updating the `pg_class` table to point to the existing `reltablespace` and `relfilenode`. But it didn't help me fully since I was not able to change the database OID. Is there a way so that we can create a database instance on another database server with he same database OID?

Comment: Manually updating system tables is thought to be very bad idea.  With a bit of luck you can corrupt your database beyond repair.

Answer (score 1):

A table belongs to *one* database. Period. You can share a tablespace among databases of the *same* DB-cluster, but you cannot share a table.

But you can use [`dblink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html) for what you have in mind. This way you can query tables from a different database - even from a different DB-cluster on a different server. Simple `SELECT` queries on the same server are very fast. [Try this search](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D%20dblink) for code examples.

Or look at [`CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createforeigntable.html) for a very similar functionality. For now, I prefer dblink, because it is mature and stable. The new [SQL/MED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/MED) features (Management of External Data) [`FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) and [`FOREIGN TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createforeigntable.html) are still in the making ..